# add array element from file into json array of other file with jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to add an array element into an existing json file using jq.

**element.json**

```
{
  "category": "fiction",
  "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
  "title": "Sword of Honour",
  "price": 12.99
}
```

**original.json**

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I tried following

```
jq ".store.book += [input] "  original.json  element.json
```

Above works fine and it added array and show output like below

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Now two questions

- First i tried to save updated output in original.json with below but it emptied my both files

  `jq ".store.book += [input] "  original.json  element.json > original.json`

then i used but sponge is not installed and i cant install it on production

```
jq ".store.book += [input] "  original.json  element.json | sponge original.json
```

Following is working for First

```
jq ".store.book += [input] "  original.json  element.json > original.tmp && mv original.tmp original.json
```

- Second i want that before adding array i change the value of **price** and then add in **original.json**

EDIT1:
As per feedback i tried below but for second still error

```
jq ".store.book += [input.price=2] "  original.json  element.json
```

It throws error

```
jq: error (at element.json:6): Invalid path expression near attempt to access element "price" of {"category":"fiction","aut...
```

Comment: @Dmitry i was not able to install jtc with "yum install jtc" on centos, Most of Administrator dont like Copying binary and installaing

Comment: yes, `jtc` it not part of the packages yet (I need to work on packaging it in the near future). In meanwhile there're only 2 options: either download a binary, or compile it on your system (compiling though should be straight forward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First

```
[ input|.price |= $newprice ]
```

> Second

The simplest would be to write the output to a temporary file, and then, perhaps after checking for success, moving it into place.

Comment: [input.price |= $newprice ] is throwing "Invalid path expression near attempt to access element"

Comment: Yes, an extra | is needed. Fixed.  Thanks.